# Doc file has been corrupted error after updating VS to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.2.0 Preview 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I had the same problem with “**Docfile corruption**” error after **upgrading to 17.2**. preview 2.1 today.
I could not build, load files or even close VS without forcefully ending VS process in task manager.

[Message Box Error | Click for Show Full Size Imgae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6nay.png)

Here is what fixed it for me without having to downgrade…

1. Delete all .vs folders (Hidden Folder) from the solution
2. Delete all files in
3. Re-open project/solution and all working again.

[Message Box Error | Click for Show Full Size Imgae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxmEE.jpg)

Hope this saves someone from losing a few hours on this.

Comment: Didn't quite understand your second bullet point and the visual, but just deleting the .vs folder seemed to do it for me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Its working for me. Thank you

(the docfile has been corrupted 0x80030109 visual studio 2022 error solution)

Delete all .vs folders (Hidden Folder) from the solution

Comment: You're welcome! Best wishes to you.

Answer (score 0):

Close the solution and just delete the hidden .vs folder and start again.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the .vs files
Restarted my computer three times
Deleted the newly created .vs files

So far nothing has worked im still getting:
docfile has been corrupted 0x80030109 error.

I do have a full back up from a day or so back and all my code is updated in git 2 to 3 times a day so am considering a rollback and restore from backup and then a fresh git pull but id like to know the root cause so i can prevent this from happening again. Anyone have any other suggestions besides deleting the hidden .vs files?